# How can i accept short as argument for a function

Tags: c

I want to pass smaller integers around 0-200, hence I prefer `short`, but the code doesn't work if the arguments are referenced as `short`, the program works for `int` properly also `short` is acceptable as function return type.

```
short Random(short lowern, short uppern) {
    // blah blah
    return 23;
}
```

I get this error:

```
// Error :
c_temp.c:362:7: error: conflicting types for 'Random'
 short Random(short int lowern, short int uppern) {
       ^~~~~~
c_temp.c:362:1: note: an argument type that has a default promotion can't match an empty parameter name list declaration
 short Random(short int lowern, short int uppern) {
 ^~~~~
c_temp.c:5:7: note: previous declaration of 'Random' was here
 short Random();
```

Comment: the error says you have 2 declarations of the function.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: As the message tells you, the problem is the empty parameter list from the declaration. Just provide a proper parameter list instead of `short Random();`

Comment: `short Random();`?  Who taught you to declare functions like that?

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't have a line 362.  Please show a [mcve] and the _exact_ error message from compiling that.

Comment: Back in the days in like C80/C90 was declaring functions with an empty parameter list so that it could accept any number of parameters of any type a thing?

Comment: @SashSinha Yes, that is technically possible. But: If one wants to use this mechanism, they need to use proper types. As the message tells the OP, a type that would be converted into a larger type when calling such a function, cannot be used as parameter. You will never be able to pass a `short` as it will be converted to `int` when an empty parameter list was provided in the declaration.

Comment: @SashSinha, a function declaration with an empty parameter list *never* meant that the function accepts "any number" of arguments, in the sense that the caller can choose.  Prior to C23, it meant that the function accepts a particular, but *unspecified* number of arguments, of particular, but *unspecified* types.  It also implied that a certain pattern of type promotions should be applied to the arguments.  The caller was still responsible for passing the right number and types of arguments (as adjusted by the default argument promotions).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you have 2 different conflicting declarations:

- on line 5, you declare `Random` as `short Random();`
- on line 362, you define the function as `short Random(short lowern, short uppern)`.

The definition is incompatible with the previous declaration according to C90 (ANSI C) because the argument types cannot be inferred from the values passed: passing a `short` to a function with no prototype would let the compiler use default promotions and pass the corresponding `int` value.

Calling a function without a prototype has been specified as invalid since C99, so any calls to `Random()` with or without arguments would be incorrect, and the definition is still incompatible with the forward declaration.

Yet another change occurred in C23, where the declaration `short Random();` now means that the function should not take any argument, equivalent to the declaration `short Random(void);`, and the definition is definitely incompatible with the forward declaration.

You should use the same prototype for the declaration and the definition of the function.  Note however that there is no real gain in using the type `short` instead of `int` for the function arguments and/or the function return type, on some architectures it may actually produce more code.

Comment: And if you're using GCC, you should be using `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` and you may want to add `-Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration` — though some of those are included in `-Wall` or `-Wextra`.  See: [GCC Command Line Options — Warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html).  Using `-Werror` is key — it stops you ignoring warnings by converting all warnings to errors.  Remember: the compiler knows more about C than you do (or I do).